# What is the tag “estimations” for?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wikis

Another tag I’ve come across with no description is [estimations](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimations). I think it’s trying to cover questions involving giving or otherwise dealing with estimates, but I find the plural a bit confusing if I interpret estimation as “act or instance of estimating”.

There’s only 6 questions tagged with it, but I didn’t see a better existing tag, so I’m not sure I’d want it disappeared entirely. However, since it’s used on so few questions it probably wouldn’t be a big loss if others felt it wasn’t useful.

Comment: Best guess would be someone looked at estimates versus estimation and went with the right word but incorrect number. I see arguments both for removing it and renaming it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that come to mind when I see `estimates` (or variation):

1. Time estimates. Examples: how long a task will take, how long a customer/partner/whoever will take to get back to us.
2. Financial estimates: costs of labor, parts, etc.; profits/losses of taking on a project.

I vote to keep it. We could rename it or split it off into different tags (e.g. `time-estimates`, `cost-estimates`, etc.)? Although I think at this point splitting it might be too granular.

Comment: Except it isn’t “estimates” it is “estimations”, which isn’t a variation, it’s a different word with a different meaning.

Comment: @ColleenV I looked up the words in different dictionaries to confirm my understand of the words. While estimation can have several meanings, both [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/estimation#) (definition 3) and [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/estimation?q=estimation) (definition 2) state, in different words, that estimation can be an approximate calculation. However, given that there could be confusion as to the meaning, maybe it's best to rename the tag to `estimates`?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking it should be “estimates” too, but I wasn’t sure if other people cared or even saw an issue.

Comment: I, personally, did not see an issue until now. I always assumed that estimation stemmed from estimate, meaning approximate calculation. Only now did I learn that estimate could also be a judgment about the value of someone or something (and not specifically about the quantity of a number).